# Check if thread has OpenGL context

Tags: opengl, c++, multithreading

I'm looking for a way to check if a thread accessing a namespace function has a OpenGL context attached to it. I have looked around and all I can find is,

```
GLFWwindow* glfwGetCurrentContext();
```

Which will return NULL if there is no context, but is there a better way?

I'm using OpenGL 4.5 and GLFW 3.2

Comment: Could you elaborate about your concern with glfwGetCurrentContext? What makes you believe something else would be "better"? What would "better" look like in your opinion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know that's the best solution to check if there is an active context.

Comment: Thank's I was not too sure, It seems a little messy, but if it gets the job done, then that's all that matters :)